# Geometry nodes: Falling Tetris blocks into position

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm pretty new to geometry nodes and Blender in general.I've made a collection out of Tetris blocks in a 4x10 rectangle. Then I used a Instance to Points node on a plane to repeat this collection a bunch of times to get sort of a pathway. Now I would like to let the blocks fall "from the sky" (along Z-axis) into the ground position like you can see in the image and rest there. The animation should be offset in a cascading motion so that the blocks furthest away from the camera start falling first and get to rest position first.If possible the children of the collection should fall seperately from one another in a random order (like single Tetris blocks) but the overall motion should be as described above.

I'm a little bit lost right now in how to achieve this. I hope my explanation is clear, if not feel free to ask.

Bonus points would be if I could somehow randomize the pattern of the blocks a bit but that would be the cherry on top. ;)

[image: Geometry node setup]

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***

new node setup for the changed question:

[image]

result:

[image]

---

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works as intended except the collections move as single units (looks like a stairway) whereas I would like the single children pieces to move little bit randomly. "Seperate Childern" on the Collection Info node is checked. The Random Value node in the Instance Index input deletes some blocks randomly which is also a cool look but not exactly what I was looking for.

![Alternative Setup](https://imgur.com/a/7z9i1sj).

Comment: Please update/edit your question with that additional wishes you have (although it’s a bit unfair to extend your question afterwards) but so others won’t waste their time. Thanks.

Comment: Okay sorry I'm new to this community.

Comment: i updated my answer